# Passing email address via URL into Pardot

Tags: pardot

I'm using Pardot and I'm wondering if there's a way to pass someone's email address through a URL to allow Pardot to identify someone as a prospect as soon as they enter the site. I've found information about [passing data to Pardot forms](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264692&type=1). What I want to do is pass the information directly to Pardot, even if someone doesn't fill out a form.

Answer (score 4):

Besides that it is not seen as good practice, passing personally identifiable information in URLs, there is to my knowledge no possibility of identifying a prospect, who doesn't have a Pardot cookie, without this person having to fill out a form.

Answer (score 1):

You most definitely can do this, but as mentioned, it breaches "good etiquette" of not passing that kind of information in a URL.  You may be able to play some tricks with loading the page twice, or sending them through a small intermediate page, to make it so the visitor doesn't *notice* you put their email address right into the URL by the time they look at the URL bar ... but a web developer I worked with didn't have any luck with that when they tried it (Pardot needed longer than the first site was staying up).

But **yes**, the snippet of JavaScript that Pardot provides you and that you embed in all of your web site's pages that is responsible for setting a cookie on behalf of Pardot is also always "listening" for a "`pi_email=SomeEmailAddress`" parameter.  If that snippet of JavaScript finds such a URL parameter, **it will call out to Pardot's servers and tell Pardot** that the current "visitor ID" *(as parsed from the cookie it assigns/uses)* belongs to that email address.

Also, some JavaScript to extract the "visitor ID" from a cookie is:

```
function getPardotVisitorId() {
// Return the value of the first cookie found that starts with visitor_id.  If none found, return an empty string.
    var desiredPrefix = 'visitor_id';
    var cookieArray = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i=0; i<cookieArray.length; i++) {
        var currentCookie = cookieArray[i];
        // If the current cookie starts with a space, trim it off & overwrite the current cookie w/o the space.
        while (currentCookie.charAt(0)==' ') currentCookie = currentCookie.substring(1);
        // Test if currentCookie starts with the desired Prefix.
        if (currentCookie.indexOf(desiredPrefix) == 0) {
            // Now that we've found a cookie that starts with the Prefix, grab the rest of it.
            cookieAfterPrefix = currentCookie.substring(desiredPrefix.length,currentCookie.length);
            if (cookieAfterPrefix.split('=').length < 2) return '';
            else return cookieAfterPrefix.split('=')[1];
        }
    }
    return '';
}
```

If you want to come up with some sort of solution to your problem that involves getting the "visitor ID" back to your own servers *(perhaps doing some calls against Pardot's API from there)*, rather than putting an email address into a URL parameter, that might be handy.

It adds a bit of clutter to your "Prospect Activities" log *(although nothing you couldn't periodically manually comb the log for and delete using the Pardot REST API and a script)* because it logs each hit to https://pi.pardot.com/analytics as a unique "Visit," but for such back-end operations without using the REST API *(and the worrying about stored credentials that that entails)*, you can, once you know a visitor ID and an email address, associate them by doing a HTTP GET or POST to https://pi.pardot.com/analytics and giving it headers or parameters of:

- `ver=3`
- `visitor_id=SomeVisitorId`
- `campaign_id=something` *(see your JavaScript from Pardot for `piCId`)*
- `account_id=something` *(see your JavaScript from Pardot for `piAId`)*
- `pi_email=me@example.com`